# Simple Search results limiting not working

Tags: search, simple-search

The search is working fine however the search results are not being limited. Any ideas?

```
    {exp:search:simple_form 
        channel="about|approach|blog|job-ads|solutions|who_we_help" 
        search_in="entries"
        results="3"
        result_page="search" 
        no_result_page="search/no_results"
    }
        <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}" />
        <input id="keywords" name="keywords" placeholder="TYPE AND PRESS ENTER" type="text">
    {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean when you say "not being limited"? By number (i.e. you're getting more than 3 results per page)? Or by channel? Also: no need to add the hidden `XID` input, the tag will generate that automatically.

Comment: Limited by number

Comment: SO how many results are you actually getting in your `search:search_results` tag?

Comment: As many results as there are - there's no limit.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried and everything looks fine to me. The only thing I can think of that was different in my code is the results_page parameter, I've got search/results instead of just search.

My code:

```
{exp:search:simple_form
    channel="my|channels"
    search_in="entries"
    results="3"
    result_page="search/results" 
    no_result_page="search/no_results"
  }
```

Maybe if you change your's to search/index?

Comment: I think you're on the right track, that his result_page parameter needs to be in template_group/template_name format, but his template structure is probably different: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/search/simple.html#id3

Comment: Also, doesn't the results page need a paginate tag?

Comment: Good point Johnathan. The results parameter is the number of results per page, not the limit/total number of results. So as you said, setting pagination on the results page will change how many results are displayed at one time, but not the total number of results to display. I don't think you can actually limit the number of results as FuriousD is wanting to do. Good spot.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add a limit= parameter, you can inside your {exp:search:search_results} tag limit by count:

```
{exp:search:search_results}
  {if count <= 3}
    {title}
  {/if}
{/exp:search:search_results}
```